# setting property in odbc

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I wonder how I can set domain to a value when I am trying to connect to a SQL database in R.

Basically, I need to set Domain to cphegtd3 to be able to get to the database.

I am using the

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so",
                 Server = "servername",
                 Database = "dbname",
                 UID = "myuserid",
                 PWD = "London",
                 Domain="cphegtd3",
                 Port = 1433)
```

and I get the following error

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 42000: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myuserid'.
```

The reason it fails the username is that it does not consider `Domain="cphegtd3"`. I didn't have this issue with `RSQLServer::SQLServer()` and domain was an entry in the yaml file.

I can also connect to the database through DBeaver and DataGrip, and of course have to set domain in the setting. But I don't know how to inform odbc in R with this parameter.

Comment: (Up front: I don't know.) I cannot find "domain" in connection strings for MySQL (https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), is there another term for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment anyway ! I managed to install RSQLServer only through this command -> devtools::install_github('imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer'). Unlike ODBC RSQLServer accepts domain ...

Comment: Heads up, in case you didn't see it: Imanuel has stopped support for the package. I've been a long-time user of it for work but have migrated away because of this. I'll keep looking for "domain" hints (not sure why I was looking at MySQL), since your safe-code-future is not really ensured with his package.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ suggests using `UID=domain\username`, though it is not working for me. Since I am not admin on that system, I don't know if that's my end or config of the sql server. Regardless, that's all I'm finding, good luck.

Comment: Ahhh ... I see why I thought mysql ... you tagged it with [tag:mysql], not [tag:sql-server], I fixed it. You also tagged it [tag:rodbc], which is referring to the [`RODBC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package, distinct from the [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) package, also fixed.